# Multiple output noise analysis with LT spice

Tags: ltspice, spice

If I want to do a noise analysis I do this in LT spice:

```
.noise V(adc1) V6 dec 12 0.01 1e9
```

Where V(adc1) is the voltage for the output node of the analysis and V6 is the source.

Question: Is there a way to have two nodes in the analysis?

Sometimes I copy circuits modify one and and compare the two circuits.

Comment: haven't done spice in a while, but wouldn't you have two of these lines?

Comment: No, you can only have 1 analysis line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with switches and a step parameter that toggles the switches.

You won't be able to integrate the noise over a bandwidth in the plot window anymore, but you can use .meas to output the integrated noise to the error log e.g.

.meas out_noise INTEG(V(onoise))

[image]

Comment: Can I run this in one sim? or do I have to run the sim twice? If I have to run the sim twice then it's probably easier to change the noise statement

Comment: @laptop2d it is one simulation.

Comment: @DavidG25 It's actually two simulations, disguised by the `.step` command. I'm a bit pedantic now, but it's about the same: change a `.step` or change a `.noise` card. It's still half-automated, and could be done for more than two I/O.

Answer (score 2):

Not having tried this, I can't guarantee it will work... but here is an idea:

Create a behavioral voltage source that acts as a mux between the two nodes, and use a swept parameter to control the mux. Set the output of the mux to be the output node for your noise analyis. Something like this:

```
BX Vmux 0 V={k*V(out1)+(1-k)*V(out2)}
.noise V(Vmux) V1 dec 12 0.01 1e9
.step param k list 0 1
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: This is what Mike Engelhardt does but with voltage controlled switches.

Answer (score -1):

This tool lets you examine all the noise sources, simultaneously, and show final SNR/ENOB for a given Input VoltPP at a given FrequencyOfInterest (FOI).
I've not activated the "gargoyles", the magnetic/electric/VDD/GND trash sources.

Here are thermal distortion (opamp shifts in input offset voltage, because of heating; and resistor value shifts that cause changes in Closed Loop Gain.) and the unified presentation of all the KT/Boltzmann/Johnson random noise.

[image]

Here is the 3 opamp signal chain, to amplify a 100uVpp signal to fit a 5vpp ADC. For low noise, the first opamp uses params (UGBW, Rnoise, Rout, DC_gain) of OPA211. The Gain Set resistors are also very low values.

[image]

Comment: The question was about LT spice, thanks for playing.

Comment: They wanted to do noise analysis.

Comment: I wanted to do a specific type of noise analysis in LT spice, if you would take the time to read the question and answer the question you would have known that